# How to use the Ethereum Natural Specification Format?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, remix

I would like to make use of the Ethereum Natural Specification Format (https://github.com/ethereumproject/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Natural-Specification-Format) but I do not understand how to implement it. I have created a website which can be used with MetaMask. Then I used Remix to create a contract. I commented some functions as written in the docs. Remix provides the metadata which include the comments but how can I pass it to Web3?

Comment: Some tools generate an HTML page from the solidity code. Do you want to pass this documentation to MetaMask? If that is the case it seems it is not supported currently https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/2501.

Comment: Thanks @Ismael! I was not aware of the issue stated by the MetaMask developers.

Comment: The Aragon project is creating a new specification for that use, but it seems to still be in development https://github.com/aragon/radspec.